# If XYZ can or could?

Tags: can-could

I am drafting an invitation to some clients regarding an event our company is holding.

The template I am going off suggests closing the email with:

"It **will** be great if [FIRM] **can** RSVP by March 20th"

I am wondering if that should be **would/could** instead of **will/can** ?

Comment: I'm personally not sure, though I would prefer would/could over will/can. However both sound equally informal (and therefore clumsy) to me for an Event Invitation. If informal fits your organisation then fine, I guess, but I would use "RSVP by March 20th". "Please" is technically a superfluous addition to RSVP, but "Please RSVP by..." is probably common usage now.

Answer (score 1):

If it is an invitation then it is could/would as it is more polite and less pushing.

Grammatically, however, will/can is the **correct form**. In most of the english speaking part of the world, will/can is will be quite acceptable as it is somewhat more direct. In north-American culture verbal politeness is norm, thus could/would are the preferred choice.

Answer (score 0):

In America, at least, it's would/could.